# Why IPFS Cluster nodes cannot find each other

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ipfs, ipfs-http-client, ipfs-cli

I setup two instances for IPFS nodes. 1 IPFS for bootstrap node and 1 IPFS for client node. I already setup a private network for both IPFS nodes. I already bootstrap the 2 IPFS nodes and they can find and talk to each other. Like if I add a file in IPFS Bootstrap, the IPFS Client can query or see the file and vice versa.

Then now, I installed `ipfs-cluster-service` and `ipfs-clusterl-ctl` on both IPFS nodes. Generate and shared the same `cluster_secret` on both ipfs nodes. But when I try to run the `ipfs-cluster-service daemon`, they can't find each other. On the client node, I add a bootstrap argument for the hostname and the cluster peer id.

What could be the the reason why they can find to each other?

I also temporarily open all ports because it may be the blocker, but still they can't find each other.

Btw, I follow this tutorial https://www.geekdecoder.com/setting-up-a-private-ipfs-network-with-ipfs-and-ipfs-cluster/

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the problem. I just found out that there are two ways to bootstrap the cluster. On the tutorial that I'm following, they are using the Raft mode way. It works when I tried to use the CRDT mode. Thank you.